# inherited shared pointer failed to get_widget

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, gtkbuilder, gtkmm3

I am using a base class in c++ to imitate interface in Java, such I don't have to repeat some code or create object for every different class I create.

Basically it contains the RefPtr to a GtkBuilder, that I will use throughout the application.

But I find that the program terminates whenever I access it from the inherited class.

```
class SetupUIClass{
public:
    SetupUIClass(std::string builderResourceString, Glib::ustring baseWidgetName){
    }
    SetupUIClass(Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder, Glib::ustring baseWidgetName){
        this->builder = builder2;
        //Point A
    }
protected :
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;
}
class MyApplicationWindow: public SetupUIClass, public Gtk::ApplicationWindow{
public:
    MyApplicationWindow(std::string builderResourceString, Glib::ustring baseWidgetName){
        SetupUIClass(builderResourceString, baseWidgetName);
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder2 = Gtk::Builder::create_from_resource(builderResourceString);
        //Point B

        MyApplicationWindow(builder2, baseWidgetName);

    }
    MyApplicationWindow(Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder2, Glib::ustring baseWidgetName){
        //Point C
    }
}
```

So the variable `builder` holds the pointer to the gtkbuilder.

I use `builder->get_widget(widgetname, somewidgetpointer)` to check if my program is running ok.

At Point B I can do `builder2->` which is using the locally created pointer, program continues to run.

Then program goes into Point A, where I called the super constructor, At Point A, I can do both `builder2->` and `this->builder->`, which are respectively the pointer passed into the constructor and the protected variable, program continues to run.

however when I reach point C, where it can only access the inherited protected pointer, when I do `this->builder->get_widget`, program stops without any output or error thrown.

I am scratching my head over this. Is there something I did wrong?

- Inherited class cannot access address pointed to by the inherited protected pointer?
- the Refpointer cleaned itself and lifecycle of the gtk builder is over?
- the address changed as going from one class to another?

Any help will be appreciated. Or may be please point out if I am doing something wrong the entire time.

**UPDATE**
I did some further checking, `if(builder)` returned false in point C but not point A, that is what caused the problem. But shouldn't I have stored the builder variable already in the superclass constructor?

in the [Glib documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-refptr-copying.html.en) it states it allows copying.

Answer (score 0):

seems I was misled by some other stack posts of the syntax of calling base class constructor. after using probably proper initialization method

```
MyApplicationWindow::MyApplicationWindow(Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder2, Glib::ustring baseWidgetName):SetupUIClass(builder2, baseWidgetName){
```

instead of

```
MyApplicationWindow(std::string builderResourceString, Glib::ustring baseWidgetName){
    SetupUIClass(builderResourceString, baseWidgetName);
```

that particular problem seems solved.